# Обращение "мужчина/женщина": быть или не быть?

Tags: общие-вопросы, этикет

Честно говоря, меня такие обращения не то что коробят, мне хочется дать сдачи.))) Более хамского обращения, чем по половому признаку, я просто не знаю. Причем для женщин это оскорбительно вдвойне, потому что обращение девушка/женщина — это еще и намек на возраст, что по отношению к женщине крайне невежливо.
И, кстати, насколько я знаю, "мужчина" в начале ХХ века обращались девицы легкого поведения, зазывая клиента: "Мужчина, угостите девушку папироской".
По-моему, даже в первобытных племенах экваториальной Африки есть какие-то формы обращений друг к другу. И только у нас друг о друге говорят как о животных. Спасибо, что не "кобель" и "сука"...
А что вы думаете по этому поводу? Допустимы ли обращения по половому признаку и является ли это оскорбительным?

Comment: Уже обсуждали [здесь][1]


  [1]: http://russ.hashcode.ru/questions/2577/%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3-%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D1%83

Comment: Там обсуждали не совсем это, а вообще любые обращения. А тут речь о конкретных.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Меня тоже всегда коробят эти "мужчина", "женщина". Думаю, что самый приемлемый вариант - это обращение "уважаемый/уважаемая".

Answer (score 4):

Думаю, если в русском языке нет аналогов всяким там мисс, миссис, фрау, мадемуазель, мадам и др., значит, язык на протяжении долгого времени не нуждался в в этих уважительных обращениях, либо они заменялись на французские, когда в России была мода на всю французское.  
*"Молодой человек"* и *"девушка"* — довольно уважительно, как мне кажется. С людьми постарше всё не так просто. *"Женщина"* и *"мужчина"* звучат несколько угловато. Многие люди, видимо, так же считают, поэтому, когда обращаются к людям в возрасте, говорят *"извините"*. *"Извините"* — универсальное обращение.          
Вы, вопрошающий, пропагандируете эмансипацию в языке. По всему миру обращаются по половому признаку, иначе общение может стать слишком условным. Вы, наверное, считаете, что к людям надо относиться непредвзято, как к неграм в США. Это уже ваши личные предпочтения.

Comment: Был аналог: сударь и сударыня. Вытеснили безликим "товарищ". Мы эту тему уже обсуждали.

Comment: В конце концов "гражданочка", если хочется разговорный вариант.

Comment: Валентин, Вам выносится предупреждение за переход на личности.  
Администратор.

Comment: Что? Я никого не оскорблял. В вопросе явно выражена личная позиция автора, а я сказал, что это позиция автора и что она слишком радикальна.

Comment: Замечания администрации обсуждению не подлежат.

Answer (score 4):

[[@Noble](/users/1515/noble)](/users/1515/noble), какие варианты обращений вам нравятся? Видимо, вам привычнее универсальное бесполое "товарищ"? У каждого свои тараканы.

Или Вы предлагаете перенять практику африканских племен? Так сначала придется достичь такого же уровня социальных отношений.

---

[[@Fuchoin Kazuki](/users/3/fuchoin-kazuki)](/users/3/fuchoin-kazuki), я не знакома с Вами лично, как и с автором вопроса. Тем не менее, положа руку на сердце, скажу: не верю, что вы сами никогда не употребляете подобных обращений. Я живу в этой стране и слышу как говорят окружающие. Обращения *сударь/сударыня* в большинстве случаев звучат нелепо. Даже *товарищ* или *гражданин* звучат по сравнению с ними более органично.

Любому из нас может что-то нравиться и не нравиться. Но развитие языка не зависит от наших личных предпочтений. Если сейчас так сложилось - значит были тому причины. Если так говорит большинство (подавляющее большинство! - читай "все"), то дело не в культуре отдельного носителя языка, а гораздо глубже.

Никто не знает, каким будет наш язык через сто лет. Но он изменится обязательно. Это процесс естественный. Единственное, что можете сделать Вы лично - говорите так, как лично Вы считаете правильным. Учите своих детей или учеников говорить так, как Вы считаете правильным.

И будьте терпимее. Набивший оскомину лозунг о толерантности на самом деле очень актуален, причем во всех сферах жизни. Поймите наконец, что другой человек может думать не так как вы. И представление о культуре у него может быть иным. И не надо давать ему за это сдачи.

Comment: Я подобрых обращений не употребляю. И жаль, что Вам это странно и что Ваше воспитание позволяет Вам их употреблять. Очень жаль.
На этом читаю дискуссию исчерпанной. Пусть Вас воспитывают мама с папой.  
Кроме того, замечания администрации обсуждению не подлежат. И скажите спасибо, что я проявила так любимую ваши толерантность (признаться, меня тошнит от одного этого слова) и не вышвырнула Вас с форума за выпады в адрес задавающего вопрос.

Comment: О, вот это по-нашему! Браво! Узнаю знакомые нотки. Вы мне напомнили о славных годах моей работы в правоохранительных органах. Там тоже некоторые Высококультурные сотрудники придерживаются девиза "и скажите спасибо, что мы вас еще не посадили". Хоть я столь высокой культурой и не отличаюсь, признаюсь, у меня тоже бывало чесались руки "повышвыривать с форума". Мужайтесь, @Fuchoin Kazuki! Власть - непростое испытание. Впрочем, поступайте как считаете нужным.

Comment: Я прошу прощения,а комментарии можно править? А то в одном из двух есть две орфографические ошибки (или одна описка и одна ошибка) Можно, оказывается.

Comment: @Fuchoin Kazuki, извините, что поздно, но надо поправить.
"Я подобРых обращений...", "На этом читаю дискуссию..."(скорее всего, нужно - "считаю"), "в адрес задавающего вопрос" - по-моему, нужно "задающего".

Answer (score 3):

Вот хорошо тем славянам, которые не переживали советской власти с ее псевдодемократизмом! Например, у сербов и хорватов сохранилась троица
"господин - госпожа - господица"
которая вполне эквивалентна
"мистер - мисс - миссис",
"сеньор - сеньора - сеньорита",
"месье - мадам - мадемуазель" ...
До революции были у нас аналогичные "барин - барыня - барышня",но они уже тогда казались несколько устаревшими, а "господин - госпожа" действовали исправно. Часто звучало также "мадам" и "сударь - сударыня" при обращении без имени.
Сейчас все это едва ли восстановится. И поэтому приходится слышать довольно хамские "мужчина - женщина". 
Лично я, человек очень старый, но помнящий с детства лишь "гражданин - гражданка", изворачиваюсь как могу. Если вижу несколько мужчин за 25, обращаюсь к ним "мужики", если женщин за 25 - "дорогие дамы" (за глаза - тоже дамы), если моложе - "девушки/милые девушки", если среднеазиаты или кавказцы - "дорогие". Ничего не могу предложить и предположить на будущее, народ у нас темноват и хамоват. А вдруг появится какой-нибудь учитель нравственности, который предложит все же вспомнить "сударь - сударыня"!

Answer (score 2):

Все предложенные варианты хороши и имеют право на существование.И всё равно чаще всего слышишь "мужчина"/"женщина".

Comment: Видимо, к вам еще не обращались "бабушка".

Answer (score 2):

К сожалению, приходится признать, что эти малоэтичные обращения вошли в обиход. Языковая культура подавляющяей части нашего населения, зачастую изъясняющейся на том языке, который принято называть непечатным, есть отражение общей культуры народа. Эту часть нашего народа подобные обращения не коробят. Ввести новое обращение законодательно все равно не получится.
 Большевикам как-то удалось сделать так, что "товарищ" прижилось. А вот предлагаемые сейчас *сударь, сударыня* и прочие никак не хотят входить в язык.

Answer (score 2):

На мой взгляд, многое зависит от интонации и доброжелательности. Можно и "сударь/сударыня" с таким выражением сказать, что и отвечать не захочется. 
    Я чаще говорю просто "Извините, Вы...". Реже обращаюсь "мужчина/женщина". Но тут стараюсь занизить возрастную планку. Лучше женщину назвать девушкой, чем наоборот. Не так давно обсуждали вопрос обращения с молодыми мамочками. Они очень обижаются, когда к ним обращаются "женщина". Предпочитают "девушка". Так что универсальное обращение не помешало бы.
    Есть еще один момент, не совсем по теме, но стоящий внимания, как мне кажется. Сейчас много мужчин и женщин, испытавших радость отцовства и материнства в зрелом возрасте. Несколько раз становилась свидетелем, когда таких родителей называли дедушками/бабушками прямо или косвенно (например, "ваш внук..."). Пришла к выводу, что лучше говорить универсальное "ваш ребенок...".

Comment: Очень неприятно, что отвечающие начали переходить на личности и оскорблять спрашивающего. Не помешало бы вам (особенно это касается Валентина и yupaz) подучиться культуре общения.  
Вам выносится предупреждение за выпады в адрес автора вопроса, который, кроме того, что призывает к этой самой культуре общения, которая вам, видимо, не знакома, ничем никого не обидел.  
Администратор.

Comment: Насчет "внука" - мой случай. Но я не обижаюсь, что ж поделаешь. Сама виновата, что так затянула!  
А вот сын первое время не понимал, о ком говорят люди "твоя бабушка".  
А вообще-то все это миндальничанье с возрастом мне кажется совсем ненужным. Почему я в 50 лет должна делать вид, что я еще молодая? Что зазорного, что меня будут воспринимать такую, как есть?

Comment: Если Вы чувствуете себя бабушкой — все в порядке. А есть люди, которые в 50 лет чувствуют себя на 20. Не физически, а морально. И перед такими людьми я, как говорится, снимаю шляпу.  
И вообще, я твердо убеждена: лучше польстить человеку, чем потенциально его обидеть.

Comment: Да я не о том. Почему считается, что назвать молодым - значит польстить? А назвать бабушкой - обида? Какая-то геронтофобия :-)

Answer (score 1):

Меня коробит, когда называют меня женщиной. Особенно молодые распылившиеся женские обособи. Так смешно это звучит,  представьте я такая стройная и статная, и вдруг,  какое то ватрушеобразное существо говорит мне " женщина" . Я не реагирую, как правило, но иногда черт дергает за язык, и начинаю хамить. Потом себя ругаю, бескультурие бич нашего времени.

Answer (score 1):

Я не читал комментариев к данному вопросу. Однако я лишь немного прочитал Ваш вопрос и сразу же понял, что Вы хотите узнать. Обращения **мужчина, девушка, женщина, молодой человек, тетёнка** и так далее свидетельствуют о плохом знании этикета, потому что так обращаться к человеку нельзя. Если Вы хотите попросить человека о чём-то или призвать его внимание, то Вам следует употреблять этикетные формулым, как-то: **будьте любезны, не сочтите за труд, будьте добры, очень прошу ваc, не могли бы Вы** и так далее.

Comment: А если человек вас не видит или отвернулся, так можно ещё и в спину постучать. Тук-тук-тук, не будете так любезны...
Это вместо обращения.

Comment: Над этим я тоже думал ;) Однако автор моей книги ничего про это не рассказал.

Answer (score 0):

- Английский - "мисс" и "миссис"
- Французский - "мадам" и "мадемуазель"
- Испанский - "синьора" и "синьорита"

никого не трогает, ни носителей, ни употребителей, и это при еще более строгом смысле. Что ж истерить на родной язык? Может, стоит подучить? Не нравится "женщина-девушка" - работайте "сударыня-барышня"

Comment: Вы неверно утверждаете. Синьор и синьорита - слова, заимствованные из итальянского языка. Если же Вы про испанские сеньора и сеньорита, то тогда верно. 
http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%D0%BE%D1%80

Comment:  "мисс" и "миссис" являются обращениями при добавлении фамилии. К незнакомой женщине обращаются "Мэм" (сокращение от Madame). И не говорят "Вон, идет какая-то миссис". Для этого случая есть слово Woman -женщина. Опять-таки, слово Woman не используется для обращения. У нас же последнее время распространились обращения, дифференцированные по поло-возрастным признакам: девочка, девушка, женщина, бабушка. Пошло это от южно-русских диалектов, которые, в свою очередь, находились под влиянием культуры Кавказа. Если кто-то разбирается в системе обращений на Кавказе- прошу поделиться информацией.

Answer (score 0):

Вот хорошо тем славянам, которые не переживали советской власти с ее псевдодемократизмом! Например, у сербов и хорватов сохранилась троица
"господин - госпожа - господица"
которая вполне эквивалентна
"мистер - мисс - миссис",
"сеньор - сеньора - сеньорита",
"месье - мадам - мадемуазель" ...
До революции были у нас аналогичные "барин - барыня - барышня",но они уже тогда казались несколько устаревшими, а "господин - госпожа" действовали исправно. Часто звучало также "мадам" и "сударь - сударыня" при обращении без имени.
Сейчас все это едва ли восстановится. И поэтому приходится слышать довольно хамские "мужчина - женщина". 
Лично я, человек очень старый, но помнящий с детства лишь "гражданин - гражданка", изворачиваюсь как могу. Если вижу несколько мужчин за 25, обращаюсь к ним "мужики", если женщин за 25 - "дорогие дамы" (за глаза - тоже дамы), если моложе - "девушки/милые девушки", если среднеазиаты или кавказцы - "дорогие". Ничего не могу предложить и предположить на будущее, народ у нас темноват и хамоват. А вдруг появится какой-нибудь учитель нравственности, который предложит все же вспомнить "сударь - сударыня"!

Answer (score -1):

Ооо, суфражистки взбунтовались!
Что опять Вам не так то?
"Хамское обращение по половому признаку", как Вы, особа, выразились, является стандартной практикой в Европейских стран и США, где, к слову, уровень культуры и достатка существенно выше.
Свободы, кстати, тоже поболее. [Удосужитесь поразмыслить?]
Вы тут умудрились привести нам в пример африканские племена...А вот страны Ближнего Востока таки не упомянули.. отчего же? [подсказка: ислам]
"И только у нас друг о друге говорят как о животных." - и верно, 95% населения РФ в той или иной мере это оправдывает.
Не прыгайте за облака. :) 
edit: ах, да, в Германии лишь Фрау и Мэдхен, а Фрёйляйны остались в 19 веке.